# new LSI megaraid Sas/sata 9286CV-8e controller won't import foreign (old) disks

Tags: raid, lsi

Had a previous controller go bad -- new controller is able to see disks, but all as Foreign , unconfigured good.  There were 2 VD's, 1 in each container both arranged as RAID 10 -- 2 stripes in each container each disk in the strip mirroring.

Previous controller was definitely the problem -- as it wouldn't even see the disks, new controller comes up and lists all the physical disks, but 0 VD's (instead of the 2, expected).  Going into the webbios of the card, it says they are all a foreign config and asks if I want to import them, but no place to say y/n, only a list where it says 'All configurations' and under that, configs numbered 1-7.  Tried all, but all give 'error in reading config'.  The previous controller was a 9286CV-8e, but I never used the cache-vault feature.  I thought this new controller should have just read them in, but not.

It is a bit odd that all are marked as unconfigured good, I thought.  Have had situation before where all were marked Unconf-bad, and had to mark each good, and that was it.  But now, I was sure it should be able to read the config from the existing set.  Don't understand how it knows they are a foreign set, but can't read config in from any in either .

I hope someone has a suggestion -- as we are talking about 12*4TB and 12*2TB of data between the two drives (with 12 disks on each being mirrors).  Thanks!

Comment: Are the both controllers (old and new) the same model?

Comment: @AntonDanilov -  They were both 9286CV-8e's.  I think this model of card had at least 4 revisions since the first one I had a 'D' on the RAID Chip model, while the replacement has a 'C' on it.  Even though card was sold as 'new', I'm getting a vague feeling it isn't new, though it had no signs of use, the age of the car and it being an earlier revision made me wonder.  Suppose it is possible it was on a shelf that long, but heard of someone else buying same model who was told card was out of warrantee when they tried to get service on it even though card looked new.

Answer (score 0):

...It's working again.  It really helps if you are buying a card that apparently was old and had rather old Firmware on it.  Got a USB image and instructions from lsi->avago website, and it already had latest firmware for this card on it.

If this was something that happened "often", I probably could have had this up 3-4 days ago, as it was, had to think through all steps and approach it 'new'.  After burning in new firmware, the disks came up as Unconfig-good in green text (was a dark grey before).  And no problem importing anything.

C'est la vie.

Thanks to those who read this and sent messages...

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the card already had the latest firmware on it, what "new firmware" did you put on it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I think the card came with the original firmware it shipped with many years ago.  So I flashed it with  the firmware included in the latest USB image from the Avago website;  apparently Avago regenerates the USB and CD images when new firmware revisions come out, rather than forcing the customer to update the USB image with whatever is latest.